# What's a word for when you were right about something- but you wish that you had been wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the feeling of being right, but wishing that you had been wrong. Is there such a word?

Comment: Do you know there is such a word and you just can't remember it? Or are you just hoping?

Comment: Please show how the word will be used.